# RMI theory , download stub file

Tags: java, class, rmi, rmiregistry

When a Client asks for a remote reference to a RMIregistry, Rmiregistry sends to Client
an instance of the stub class, the client need also the definition of this class (.class) .

Client asks for stub.class to Rmiregistry or Rmiregistry sends it automatically ?

Using codebase property  Can I force Client to download stub.class from a my webserver?

Thanks

**EDIT:
It seems like if I generate stub file with rmic , then client tries to download them, if I don't use rmic client doesn't download stub, but my program works.

Can you explain this?

**FINAL EDIT:
Ok, I think to have understood.
Thanks to EJP

Regards

Comment: use codebase, share the codebase with a simple http server, register the codebase in both client and server.

Comment: @user2511414 It is only necessary to *set* (not 'register') the codebase *property* at the JVM which is sending objects whose classes the peer doesn't have in its CLASSPATH. Normally that's only the server.

Comment: @EJP thanks buddy, but I always set the codebase directory at the server too, so you mean is there anyway to just set the codebase only for client?

Comment: I repeat. You *only* have to set it at the peer which is supplying instances of classes the other peer doesn't have, and, I also repeat, normally that is the server, so normally there is no need to set it at the client at all. Try to understand that, instead of trying to tell me what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Client asks for stub.class to Rmiregistry or Rmiregistry sends it automatically ?

Neither. Either the client already has the class in its CLASSPATH or it downloads it from the codebase server if there is one. The Registry has nothing to do with it either way.

> Using codebase property Can I force Client to download stub.class from a my webserver?

Well, that's what it's *for.* It's the *only* thing it's for. Note that it has to be set *at the RMI server JVM.*

> It seems like if I generate stub file with rmic , then client tries to download them, if I don't use rmic client doesn't download stub, but my program works.

If you satisfy the conditions outlined in the class description in the Javadoc for UnicastRemoteObject you don't need to generate stubs at all.

Comment: If  codebase server is not set and client has not stub.class in its CLASSPATH, what will happen?

Comment: Hi EJP, Let me state a nice thing!
I'm using an updated java version, however just to learn I created stub file manually through RMI, at this point Client tries to download stub file, but If I don't use Rmic it doesn't, it seems there is a way to automatically create Stub.
Can you explain?

Comment: Ok, So I can conclude that:
If the java version used (from Client)is earlier than 1.5, then
Server must create stub by rmic and it must set codebase in order to allow client to download stub.class .
If an updated java version is used, rmic has not be used and client receveing stub object will can create dynamically create stub.class file and use it to unmarshall stub object received from RmiRegistry.
Is it Ok?

Comment: Not quite. You have to meet the conditions that I mentioned.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33409/discussion-between-edge7-and-ejp)

Comment: If you can come in chat, It's would be nice for me.
In every cases , your help has been very useful for me.
You are a very expert about RMI concepts.
Thanks.

Comment: Not convenient: anyway I don't believe in it. I prefer to post solutions here where everyone can see them. Did you find the documentation I referred you to?

Comment: I read this: http://nick-lab.gs.washington.edu/java/jdk1.5b/guide/rmi/relnotes.html.I learned also that The static method UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Remote) is declared to return java.rmi.server.RemoteStub and therefore cannot be used to export a remote object to use a dynamically generated stub class for its stub. An instance of a dynamically generated stub class is a java.lang.reflect.Proxy instance which is not assignable to RemoteStub.

Comment: So you didn't find it. You found something else. Try reading the documentation I cited.

Comment: It would be nice if you could post a direct link.

Comment: Are you seriously asking me here for a direct link to the Javadoc for UnicastRemoteObject?